# Entity Framework entity splitting one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-persistence

We are trying to use `EF` as a `Business Entity Mapping model`. Instead of generating 1 table per class we would like to flatten out the tables (entity splitting) and generate a business object for the class, letting Entity Framework handle the **CRUD**.

In addition we have an existing database and **cannot** modify the schema. We have tried both code-first and database first solutions, but we are unable to get to our stated goal.

What we have:

```
 public class Call
 {
    public int CallId {get;set;}
    public DateTime callTime {get;set;}
    public int PhoneTypeId {get; set;}

    public virtual PhoneType PhoneType {get; set;}
}

public class PhoneType 
{
     public int PhoneTypeId {get ;set;}
     public string TypeOfPhone {get ;set;}
}
```

What we want:

```
public class CallDetails
{    
    public int CallId {get;set;}
    public DateTime callTime {get;set;}
    public string TypeOfPhone {get; set;}
}
```

**Edit**

We are on ef 5 but can go up to ef 6.

**Edit**

To state the question clearer, I am looking for a way to flatten out multiple tables into 1 single entity, then have EF automagically update the multiple tables when that one edit is saved back to the data context

**Edit**

Is there a way of mapping 1 entity to second, if the first entity has the primary key of the second and the second entity doesnt have any key relating back to the first?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you working with?

Comment: @HimBromBeere updated with exact question

Comment: @dave updated with ef version

Comment: Can you give more details about how entity splitting didn't work?  This article appears to describe how to do exactly what you're asking:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715646.aspx

Comment: Show us the code you tried in Code First ?

Comment: You title says *entity splitting one to many*, which is a contradictio in terminis. But the example is 1:1. So what do you mean? Maybe showing the database schema could shed some light on this.

Comment: @GertArnold   The example is 1 - Many if you look at it from the phonetype. There is 1 phonetype with many phones

Comment: OK, so, no entity splitting here.

Comment: You basically look for a way to have children copy some values from their parents. EF doesn't provide any mapping strategy for that.

Comment: @GertArnold that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: @GertArnold The only thing that comes close to what I want, is that both entites Must share the same key.  Can we create a mapping where 1 entity has the key of the second, but the second entity doesnt have the key of the first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103649/discussion-between-gh9-and-gert-arnold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like how EF builds the class for you, create your own just as you want it. (I wrote the following assuming you have C# 6)

```
public class CallDetails
{
    public Call entityCall { get; set;}
    public int CallId => entityCall.CallId;
    public DateTime callTime {
            get{ return entityCall.callTime;}
            set{ entityCall.callTime = value;}
        }
    public string TypeOfPhone => entityCall.PhoneType.TypeOfPhone;
}
```

Then when you use it

```
var details = new CallDetails(){ entityCall = db.Calls.Find(id) };
```

You can access the values in the structure that you set up.That being said, I'd suggest using EF's classes. Doing it this way can cause a headache when it comes to editing values in the database.